# How to add image into center of svg circle?

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, svg

I am trying to add an image into the center of a SVG circle.
I tried with patterns

```
<pattern id="image_birds" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100" width="100">
<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="birds.png" height="50" width="50"></image>
</pattern>
```

But it does not center the image. I am working with Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. What I did is adding a [filter](http://www.svgbasics.com/filters1.html) to my svg:

```
<filter id = "i1" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "birds.png"/>
</filter>
```

and in the circle add attribute:

```
circle.setAttribute('filter','url(#i1)');
```

Comment: that looks like a hack

Answer (score 7):

Clipping should do what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking

Something like:

```
<clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
</clipPath>

<image x="25" y="25" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/150.png" height="150" width="150" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" ></image>
```

You can see the result of this example here: http://jsbin.com/EKUTUco/1/edit?html,output

Up to you to center the images in javascript according to their sizes, via `x` and `y` attributes.

Comment: Thanx but i did it eventually with filter [link](http://www.svgbasics.com/filters1.html)

Comment: ok. two things you should check: 1. whether you need IE9 support (filters are only supported as of IE10, clips work in IE9) 2. performance, in case your application does intensive client-side processing. Filters might be slower than clip.

Comment: Thanks filter is slower than clipping but it did the work for me.